# Name for this property closely related to subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, terminology

A *subadditive* function is a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ with the following property :
$$ \forall x, y \in A,~~~~~f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y),$$
where both $A$ and $B$ are closed under addition.

I'm wondering if there is a name for the following closely related property :
$$ \exists M > 0, \forall x, y \in A,~~~~~ f(x+y) \leq M\Big(f(x) + f(y)\Big).$$

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-6324-7_19) seems to discuss even more general versions of subadditivity.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Very many thanks.

Comment: Once I asked a question on terminology and I was told "What is wrong with coinage". Well, nothing, but I suffer from the impostor's syndrome and I would rather let coinage to native english speakers.

Comment: While I agree with you on that one, I also agree with Gauss, who famously said: "What we need are notions, not notations". So as long as everyone can understand the notions that you talk about, you should not worry too much about the notation, i.e. terminology in this case.